# How to add a component using a preexisting component?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I want to do is, instead of using `Rigidbody foo = gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>()` and then manually changing each parameter of the Rigidbody to what I want it to be like, this way: 
`foo.isKinematic = false` ... `foo.mass = 4.544f` ... etc.

I want to be able to add a **WHOLE** Rigidbody to it, if that makes sense.
Something like this:

```
Rigidbody foo = anotherGameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>() = foo; //Or AddComponent<Rigidbody>() :/ neither work
```

But this just gives me an error: 
`jointsHandler.cs(48,17): error CS0131: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68856393/7111561) it  is not really possible / recommended.

Yes, there is Reflection, however, if anyhow possible **don't use it**! It is always extremely expensive / slow and dangerous / instable.

We don't know how exactly the built-in Unity components work except you look into the [source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference) - which for `Rigidbody` isn't open .. so you would need to look into a [decompiled version](https://github.com/duanjiahao/UnityDecompiled/blob/master/UnityEngine/UnityEngine/Rigidbody.cs) which might already be not complete.

And now specific to the `Rigidbody` it gets even worse!

If you look at a decompiled Version you will find: It has no **fields** at all, only **properties** which all point to some extrenal `c++` method that is hidden in the DLL. So basically it hides everything in the underlying `c++` layer or even deeper inside the Physics engine.

So what you *could* use in this case is [`Type.GetProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties#System_Type_GetProperties_System_Reflection_BindingFlags_) like e.g. (**I strongly recommend to not use this**)

```
// I intentionally do not generalize this to just any component type
// since some might have fields, others properties and for now we don't know exactly 
// what we want to copy and what not
public Rigidbody CloneAndAddRigibody(Rigidbody source, GameObject targetObject)
{
    var type = typeof(Rigidbody);
    var newRb = targetObject.AddComponent<Rigigbody>();
    // NonPublic is probably not requried / shouldn't be used
    // usually if Unity doesn't give you access to soemthing you don't want to f*** with it ^^
    var propertyInfos = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instace | BindingFlags.Public);

    foreach(var propInfo in propertyInfos)
    {
        // Skip read-only properties
        // we are only interrested in the ones we can set
        // Also skip ones we can not read ... pretty uncommon but theoretically possible
        if(!propInfo.CanWrite || !propInfo.CanRead) continue;

        // some "special" properties you might want to skip .. or not ? .. depending on your needs
        if(propInfo.Name == (nameof(Rigidbody.name))
           || propInfo.Name == (nameof(Rigidbody.tag))
           || propInfo.Name == (nameof(Rigidbody.hideFlags))) continue;

        propInfo.SetValue(newRb, propInfo.GetValue(source));
    }

    return 
}
```

But I would really rather go with "manual" It is way more efficient and also way saver. You never know what hidden properties a Unity built-in component might eventually have. Especially the ones that are **references** might screw your components behaviour completely.

And most of the time you don't need **all** of them anyway. Make sure what **you** are using in your application and then you can write a central method that simply copies these requried values over via the according properties.

---

Now this is just another wild guess but it is totally possible to simply create a complete clone of your original `Rigidbody` gameObject including its entire hierarchy:

```
var newObject = Instantiate(origin);
```

Comment: The Instantiate(origin) just might do the job! I'll let you know. Thank you for the informative answer! I'll mark it as one after I see something.

Answer (score 2):

After some research and with the help of fellow devs.

This may not be the answer you are looking for, but as of now, there are no reliable way to copy / deep clone a unity component.

There was a developer recommend a [possible solution](https://answers.unity.com/questions/458207/copy-a-component-at-runtime.html), but you can read the comments that there are still risk of failing to copy certain components.

Comment: I decided to convert my comments into another answer .. I think it might be possible with some adjustments ... but I hope we both emphasized enough how unreliable and not recommended it is  ;)

Comment: @derHugo Yep I saw it. That is a informative answer, thanks for the attempt.